# Extract part of one column and save into another file using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a requirement to extract fields from a csv file. There are two columns `billing_info` and `key_id`.  `billing_info` is a object which has multiple data items in curly braces.   I need to extract  `billing_info.id_encrypted`, key_id into a different file.

**input.csv**

```
  billing_info,key_id
    {id: '1B82', id_encrypted: '1Q4AW5bwyU', address: 'san jose', phone: '13423', country: 'v73jyqgE='},bf6-96f751
```

**output.csv**

```
 billing_info.id_encrypted,key_id
 1Q4AW5bwyU,bf6-96f751
```

May i know how to use awk command to extract the data in format mentioned in output.csv. Please help

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong with your code because you did not provide it or the errors you encountered. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Making some assumptions:

- the first line of input lists the column names
- the brace-delimited element contains an arbitrary number of comma-separated key-value pairs
- key-value pairs can appear in an arbitrary order
- values are delimited by single-quotes
- commas cannot appear inside keys or values
- single-quotes do not appear anywhere else

```
<csvfile | awk -F, '
    BEGIN {
        getline
        print "billing_info.id_encrypted,key_id"
    }
    {
        for (i=1; i<NF; i++)
            if ($i ~ /id_encrypted/)
                split($i, e, /\047/)
        print e[2] "," $NF
    }
'
```

Notes:

- `-F,` splits input lines into comma-separated fields
- `BEGIN` section handles the header

  - we output the header even if there is no input
- `for` loop runs through all the fields (except the final one)
- `($i ~ /id_encrypted/)` looks for any that contain the key word
- `split` splits that field on single-quotes (`/\047/`)
- `print` outputs the value found, and the final field

Comment: If you got rid of the getline in the BEGIN section you could do that part more robustly in an FNR==1 section without getline (e.g. consider an empty file as input). See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for the issues with getline and how to call it.

Comment: Not entirely as it still uses getline in a BEGIN section. Just replace the BEGIN section with `FNR==1{print $1".id_encrypted", $2}` or similar.

Comment: I guess I don't like testing every line of input when I know it can't match. And if we're following Postel's law (testing for empty input even though it should really always contain at least a header), we need to output the new header regardless (which my original and your suggestion don't) or we're producing malformed output.

Comment: That depends if you believe the output header should be hard-coded in your script or just copied from the input header values. I prefer the latter so you don't tightly couple your code to specific values of the data it's designed to parse and given that if there's no input then there can't be any output. I get not wanting to test every line of input but IMHO the minuscule performance hit is very rarely worth the extra code necessary to use getline robustly in the BEGIN section to avoid that.

Comment: I think I believe the output header should match whatever is consuming it expects to see (which we don't know in this case). But I agree with trying to minimise coupling. Thanks for the feedback and the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast and elegant solution using awk:

`awk -F ":" '{split($3,arr1,",");split($6,arr2,",");print arr1[1] "," arr2[2]}' input.csv > output.csv`

With an explanation:

`-F ":"` make the awk field separator `:`

`split($3,arr1,",")` split the 3rd field by the `,`into array having 2 elements.

`split($6,arr2,",")` split the 6th field by the `,`into array having 2 elements.

Then print out the first element in `arr1` and the second element in `arr2`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you just convert your whole input to CSV and THEN you can trivially extract whatever fields you like from it using awk or Excel or any other tool, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1 {
    split($0,hdr)
    next
}
{
    fld[1] = fld[2] = $0
    sub(/,[^,]*$/,"",fld[1])
    gsub(/^{|}$/,"",fld[1])
    sub(/.*,/,"",fld[2])
    # print "trace: " hdr[1] "=<" fld[1] ">" | "cat>&2"
    # print "trace: " hdr[2] "=<" fld[2] ">" | "cat>&2"

    numTags = split(fld[1],tags,/'[^']*'/,vals)
    delete tags[numTags--]
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        gsub(/^, *|: *$/,"",tags[tagNr])
        gsub(/^'|'$/,"",vals[tagNr])
        # print "trace:    " tagNr ": <" tags[tagNr] "=" vals[tagNr] ">" | "cat>&2"
    }
}
FNR == 2 {
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        printf "%s.%s%s", hdr[1], tags[tagNr], OFS
    }
    print hdr[2]
}
{
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        printf "\"%s\"%s", vals[tagNr], OFS
    }
    printf "\"%s\"%s", fld[2], ORS
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
billing_info.id,billing_info.id_encrypted,billing_info.address,billing_info.phone,billing_info.country,key_id
"1B82","1Q4AW5bwyU","san jose","13423","v73jyqgE=","bf6-96f751"
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 4th arg to `split()`. Uncomment the `print trace` lines to see what each step is doing if you like. You don't need to add the double quotes around each output field if you remove or replace any commas within each field (esp. the address).